# OracleDataReader returns no rows

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a table in Oracle database and it has thousands of records in it.
I can see these records when I execute a query via PL/SQL developer.
But I can not see any record in Visual Studio, language C#

I'm using Oracle.DataAccess 2.121 (I've also tried Oracle.ManagedDataAccess) .net framework versions 3.5 to 4.6

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("user id=myUser;password=myPass;data source=DB09PROD"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT sid1,sid3,sip_no,c,si,mn,p,s,cr,mo,ni,v FROM ARL_SPEKTRO_TAB", con))
        {
            OracleDataReader rsKayit = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rsKayit.HasRows)
            {
```

Comment: Are you sure you connected the same DataBase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reasons of this:

- You may have uncommitted changes on your active session (on another session) so that Data cannot be fetched from data reader.
- You may be connecting to different database (check the DB09PROD TNS entry)
- You may be connecting to different schema where there is table with the same name on the connected schema.

You need to narrow down the possibilities first.